# How to do Data Modelling in Graph Database (Neptune) for Social Media Application related Use Case?

Tags: database-design, graph-databases

Probable Use case : 
a. Users can follow each others. It can be mutual or one-sided 
b. Users can create a post represented in text, video, image etc. 
c. Other Users can react (likes), can comment on the posts.  
d. Posts can be viewed with the content, and also the various comments and reactions of the users (along with user thumbnail and name beside the comment) in the sorted order.  
e. Comments can be deleted or post can be deleted.  
f. Number (count) of likes or comments can be viewed.

What would be ideal data designing of the Graph Database (Neptune preferably) in order to achieve the above requirement? 
 
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one option:

![social network model] (https://maxdemarzidotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/grittier-model2.png)

Comment: Thanks. Much Appreciated !